# Could anyone explain me this AWK command please?

Tags: command-line, awk

```
awk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Hello Guys,
I am learning linux, i would ask weird doubts, please do not hesitate to answer. Can anyone explain clearly the above command.

Comment: Read `man awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It instruct awk to use `:` as field (aka column) separator for each line in the file `/etc/passwd` and print the first field (`$1`) from each line to the standard output. See [gnu awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for all the details on what `awk` can do for you.